# Difference between refreshing page and closing browser and loading again

Tags: javascript, client, refresh, storage

I'm working on a Facebook-like chat application for a website and am currently working on client side javascript. When I have a chatbox open and refresh the page, I saved the open chatbox objects in the client storage so I can display them again when the page is refreshed or closed/open.

Everything works great when the user refreshes the page or links to a page within the website. But when the user closes the webpage and returns to it immediately after. The CSS is messed up so my question is: How is refreshing a webpage different than leaving a page and returning to it.

Comment: it sounds like their cache is being cleared

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm testing out this bug in Google Chrome and I'm not clearing any browser data.

Answer (score 0):

Telling the browser to load a page again (e.g. through a loopback redirection) will cause it to fetch as many resources as it can from the cache, but if the client invokes a refresh/reload, all cached resources are cleared and downloaded again. Note that in many browsers, just pressing "refresh" actually just loads the page again, and there is another command for a true cache-clearing refresh.

Comment: That makes more sense. Maybe I need to use something called an application cache. Hopefully I am in the right direction